# Concourse: Upload to artifactory fails with curl error (outstanding read data remaining)

Tags: artifactory, cloud-foundry, concourse, cf-bosh

I want to automatically discover new stemcell versions on pivnet, download them from [pivotal network](https://network.pivotal.io) and upload them to a local artifactory.
However, the upload (to artifactory) task fails with the following error:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100  410M    0     0  100  410M      0   439M --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  440M

curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

I get this error on uploading any kind of release and stemcell.

My pipeline configuration looks like this:

```
---
resource_types:
  - name: artifactory
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: pivotalservices/artifactory-resource
  - name: pivnet
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: pivotalcf/pivnet-resource
      tag: latest-final    

resources:
- name: git-repository
  type: git
  source:
    uri: ssh://<git-repository>
    private_key: ((ssh_key))

- name: stemcell
  type: pivnet
  check_every: 1m
  source:
    api_token: ((pivnet-api-token))
    product_slug: stemcells    

- name: artifactory
  type: artifactory
  source:
    endpoint: https://((artifactory_domain)):443/artifactory
    repository: "/<path>/stemcells/bosh-vsphere-esxi-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent"
    regex: "bosh-vsphere-esxi-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent-(?<version>.*).tgz"
    username: ((artifactory_username))
    password: ((artifactory_password))    

jobs:
- name: download-and-upload
  plan:
  - get: <git-repository>
  - get: stemcell
    trigger: true
    version: every
  - task: rename-files
    file: <git-repository>/tasks/rename-stemcell/task.yml
  - put: artifactory
    params: { file: renamed-stemcell/stemcell/bosh-vsphere-esxi-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent*.tgz }
...
```

I use the concourse version `v3.9.1` and the stemcell `bosh-vsphere-esxi-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent/3468.21`. Concourse is deployed as a BOSH release.

Any hints what could be the root cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to manually issue the curl command which resulted in the same error.
Then, I tried to upload the stemcell manually.
By this, it came out that there were missing `deploy` permissions on artifactory.